# How to successfully write to a .DAT file contents in a vector using C++?

Tags: c++, file, vector, data-structures, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to write to a .DAT file my list of saved patients that are stored in a vector named PatientsInSystem. However, it won't work for some reason. Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

```
if (!PatientsInSystem.empty()) {
            cout << "Error. There are still patients checked in. They must be checked out before quitting." << endl;
            cout << "Printing remaining patients in the system... " << endl;
            for (int i = 0; i < PatientsInSystem.size(); i++) {
                cout << "Patient's ID: " << PatientsInSystem.at(i)->getID() << endl;
                cout << "Patient's Name: " << PatientsInSystem.at(i)->getFirstName() << " " << PatientsInSystem.at(i)->getLastName() << endl;
                cout << "Patient's Birthday: " << PatientsInSystem.at(i)->getBirthDate() << endl;
                cout << "Patient's Primary Doctor's ID: " << PatientsInSystem.at(i)->getPrimaryDoctorID() << endl;
            }
        }
        else {
            outFile.open("CurrentPatients.dat", ios::out | ios::binary);
            if (!outFile.is_open()) {
                cout << "File not open." << endl;
            }
            else {
                cout << "Binary file open, saving patients now...\n";
                cout << "----------------------------------------\n";
                for (int i = 0; i < PatientsInSystem.size(); i++) {
                    Patient * p;
                    p = PatientsInSystem.at(i);
                    outFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char *> (&p), sizeof(p));
                }
            }

            outFile.close();
```

***[This next section of code is the same as above only edited after the first amount of help received]***

Here is the edited version of the code...
PatientList is my temporary vector which must be emptied for PatientsInSystem vector to write to the file

```
case 'q': {

        if (!PatientList.empty()) {
            cout << "Error. There are still patients checked in. They must be checked out before quitting." << endl;
            cout << "Printing remaining patients in the system... " << endl;
            for (int i = 0; i < PatientList.size(); i++) {
                cout << "Patient's ID: " << PatientList.at(i)->getID() << endl;
                cout << "Patient's Name: " << PatientList.at(i)->getFirstName() << " " << PatientList.at(i)->getLastName() << endl;
                cout << "Patient's Birthday: " << PatientList.at(i)->getBirthDate() << endl;
                cout << "Patient's Primary Doctor's ID: " << PatientList.at(i)->getPrimaryDoctorID() << endl;
            }
        }
        else {
            outFile.open("CurrentPatients.dat", ios::out | ios::binary);
            if (!outFile.is_open()) {
                cout << "File not open." << endl;
            }
            else {
                cout << "Binary file open, saving patients now...\n";
                cout << "----------------------------------------\n";
                for (int i = 0; i < PatientsInSystem.size(); i++) {
                    outFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char *> (PatientsInSystem.at(i)), sizeof(Patient));
                }
            }

            outFile.close();
```

Comment: You're trying to write only when `PatientsInSystem.empty() == true`.

Comment: Cast is not a good idea. Use operators() instead. For Testing, Print the result of reinterpret_cast<char *> (PatientsInSystem.at(i)), sizeof(Patient)) to std::cout too. Is the result on the screen that what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you are using an array of pointers vs a flat array of structs?

You are writing the local pointer variable `p`, instead of the Patient data. You would just pass `p` instead of `&p` (or just pass .at() directly), and the bytes parameter should be `sizeof(Patient)`.

If these are pointers to different sized derived classes, this has issues.

Also, the loop won't every be entered, because its in the block entered when `.empty()` is true.

Comment: Yeah, the array of pointers is because the professor asks for it.

Also I edited the .empty() part, as well as changed &p to p (or .at()) and changed to sizeof(Patient)

However it still won't write to the .dat file.. Is there something I may be missing?